# Possible to run a C++ dll in a medium trust environment?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, medium-trust

I have an issue with an open source C++ project that I have been using where when I run it on my development machine (full trust) it works fine.  When I deploy it to my hosting environment my site throws the following error:

> System.IO.FileLoadException: Unverifiable code failed policy check.

From what I have read this is because my hosting environment runs in medium trust.  Are there any settings in the C++ project that I can change to make this dll usable in a medium trust environment?

**Update:**

After doing some more investigation based on @shf301's answer, I found this quote in the documentation for [the project I am working with](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/CABCompressExtract.aspx):

> The second project is for .NET developers. I wrote a wrapper in
>   Managed C++ around this C++ project. The result compiles into a .NET
>   DLL.

Doesn't this mean that the code should run in Medium trust?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the C++ code managed?  Otherwise it's a DLL, not an assembly.  An assembly is a .NET concept, it doesn't apply to unmanged DLL's.

If the DLL is unmanaged or it's managed and contains native code, then [you can't use it in a medium trust environment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648344.aspx#paght000020_developingformediumtrust).

Your options are to change trust environment you are running or rewriting the library so it is completely managed code.

Comment: Ok, so it sounds like it is possible.  What would I need to do to change the project to be completely managed code?  If you could point me in the right direction that would be awesome.  Sorry I have very little C++ experience.

Comment: @AbeMiessler If you can do it completely managed, you can write it in C# instead. If it needed to be C++ it might be because some native code was needed.

Comment: @shf301 - Please take a look at my update if you have a moment.  I did some more research based on your answer.

Comment: @AbeMiessler - no it still won't work.  The C++/CLI wrapper still contains un-managed code (C++/CLI lets you mix managed and unmanaged).  It would take a complete rewrite to change it.  You're best bet would be to use one of the completely managed ZIP libraries like SharpZipLib